# Interfacing PS/2 or USB Keyboard to FPGA

Tags: usb, fpga, uart, ttl

I would like to connect a PS/2 or USB keyboard to FPGA. My development board is not popular named Logifind's ALINX309 where I have a mini USB uart connection and 2 40 pin I/O pins.

I did my search on internet and I was able to find an adapter of USB to TTL. I'm still not sure if it would be the right device to buy, even if it how would I connect the jumper cable from the adapter to mini USB uart port.

Link to the adapter:
http://alexnld.com/product/new-upgrade-pl2303hx-usb-to-rs232-ttl-chip-converter-adapter-module/

Kind guide me if anyone can. Thanks

Comment: You're probably asking an XY question; what are you actually trying to do?  Attaching a USB-anything to your FPGA requires a USB host controller.  The adapter you mention (you didn't read its name correctly) connects to either a USB host controller or a UART; does your board have either interface?  That adapter definitely will not allow you to connect any kind of keyboard.  *"I have a mini USB uart connection"* -- That's nonsensical; it's either USB or UART, and not a conbination.  It could be a UART TTL interface, or a RS-232 interface, or a USB interface for a CDC ACM device.

Comment: This is exactly what I have on my datasheet.
CP2102 from SILICON® 
convert UART signals to the appropriate USB standar
d. In order to use USB-UART module on AX309, 
you must first install cp2102 drivers on your compu
ter. 

Here is a snap from the board:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/714/B4odCb.png

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.  The board manufacturer splurged, and installed a  USB-to-serial-TTL adapter for you.  FYI that [CP2102 chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/cp2102.pdf) performs the same USB-to-serial-TTL function as that adapter you're contemplating (but uses a more common [Prolific chip](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PL2303HX.pdf)).  But none of this makes any sense as to how it relates to your keyboard-to-FPGA question.  You're probably asking an XY question.